# Creating rows with ExpressionEngine and a Grid using Switch

Tags: grid, switch

So far I was able to create rows with EE and a Grida data based on a solution from [that](http://bytesofpi.com/post/42026473860/creating-rows-with-expressionengine-and-a-grid) article, but new template is not able to create rows (code below)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="media" url_title="{segment_2}" limit="1" dynamic="no"}    
...
<div class="row">
        {press_releases}
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <a href="{site_url}pdfs/press/{press_releases:pdf}" target="_blank">
                    <img src="{press_releases:cover}" alt="{press_releases:title}" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
        </div>
        {switch='|||</div><div class="row">'}
        {/press_releases}     
        </div>        
....
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

any clue what is missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're wanting the switch tag to apply to the grid rows, then you need to prefix it with your grid field name ([docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/grid.html#switch)):

```
{press_releases:switch='|||</div><div class="row">'}
```